# Symfony JMS i18nRoutingBundle - separation between front and backend

Tags: php, symfony, routes, translation

I am using JMS I18nRoutingBundle and I wonder if there is a possibility to separate current selected language of frontend and backend. If I select DE language for example in frontend, then in my admin panel, fields are translated to German language as well, but should always be default language. I use `options: { i18n: false }` for admin routes. If I change language to default in front end, then backend works well. Is it possible to set backend to be always default language?

Comment: Answer is here http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/1.3.html Goto 6. Advanced